# How do I navigator.push a showModalBottomSheet for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I navigator.push a showModalBottomSheet for flutter?

```
class SetRepeatButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetRepeatButtonState createState() => _SetRepeatButtonState();
}

class _SetRepeatButtonState extends State<SetRepeatButton> {

  void _repeatMenu(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (builder) => FlatButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        textColor: Colors.grey,
        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
        disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
        onPressed: () async {
          final result = await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _repeatMenu()),
          );
        },
        child: Row(

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: showModalBottomSheet is a function, i think you should not push it. Also MaterialPageRoute.builder will ask you a Widget in return

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achieve?
if just to show the bottomsheet, just call the function in on press. 
but it will be a little different if you want to catch the variable passed from the bottomsheet to the main context

you can try like this to show bottomsheet

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: SetRepeatButton(),
    );
  }
}

class SetRepeatButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetRepeatButtonState createState() => _SetRepeatButtonState();
}

class _SetRepeatButtonState extends State<SetRepeatButton> {
  void _repeatMenu(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Text'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: Colors.grey,
          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
          disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
          onPressed: () async {
            _repeatMenu(context);
          },
          child: Text('Text'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```